# How to apply End(xlToRight) to a table on a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

The code below searches column A of the new templates, finds the relevant value in column A of the old template, copies and pastes the relevant row from the old template into the new one.

The templates are proper Excel Tables. When the row gets copied, I want to select up until there is data.
When I execute the `.End(xlToRight)` my debugger goes to column"-4161".

I don't want to select copy the entire row because then my table expands too much.

```vb
Sub copyrows()
Dim i As Integer, searchedrow As Integer, searchheader As Object

For i = 1 To 13

    Set searchheader = Sheets("New Input Template").Cells(i, 1)

    searchedrow = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    searchedrow = Sheets("Old Input Template").Columns(1).Find(what:=searchheader.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    If searchedrow <> 0 And Cells(searchedrow, 1).Value <> "" Then
    
        Sheets("Old Input Template").Range(Cells(searchedrow, 1), Cells(searchedrow, 1).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("New Input Template").Cells(i, 1)
    
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing a vlookup?

Comment: All your calls to `Cells()` should be qualified with a reference to a specific worksheet, otherwise your code may error if the active worksheet is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: I qualified using: Sheets("Old Input Template").Range(Sheets("Old Input Template").Cells(searchedrow, 1), Sheets("Old Input Template").Cells(searchedrow, 1).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("New Input Template").Cells(i, 1)

and it seemed to work

I tried qualifying before with a "Range" in there and it didn't work so I didn't think that was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't specifying the proper range in the correct area. Try the following and try to use variable for sheets instead of hard coding...

Also be careful that no columns are hidden as it will skip them when using `xlToRight`.

```
Sub copyrows()
Dim i As Integer, searchedrow As Integer, searchheader As Object
Dim oldWs As Worksheet
Set oldWs = Sheets("Old Input Template")


For i = 1 To 13

    Set searchheader = Sheets("New Input Template").Cells(i, 1)

    searchedrow = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    searchedrow = oldWs.Columns(1).Find(what:=searchheader.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    If searchedrow <> 0 And Cells(searchedrow, 1).Value <> "" Then

    Range(oldWs.Cells(searchedrow, 1), oldWs.Cells(searchedrow, 1).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("New Input Template").Cells(i, 1)
    
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```